# Oracle timestamp rounding

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have a date with the value - 08.06.16 19:56:20,473000000 in orcle db.

```
CR_DATE - TIMESTAMP(6)
```

I need the date to be truncated to the top of the prior hour and converted to epoch format. For example if the date is as mentioned above then it should get rounded to 08.06.16 19:00:00 and then converted to epoch which should give me final o/p as 1465412400

I can use the below query to change to epoch format but with that rounding to nearest hour is not working.

```
ROUND((CAST(CR_DATE AS DATE) - DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60, 0) AS creationDate
```

If I use

```
select CR_DATE,TRUNC(CREATION_DATE, 'HH24')  AS creationDate
```

then I get the value as 08.06.16 and the HH:MM details gets truncated.

The NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT set in DB is DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF

Can someone help me to fix this without changing the NSL Format ?

Comment: You say "rounded to the nearest hour" but your example seems to show that you want to truncate to the top of the prior hour.  Which of the two is correct.  `trunc(creation_date, 'HH24')` will return a `date` truncated to the hour.  Your client may not display the time portion but it is still there.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.Yes it is truncate to the top of the prior hour and actually to the nearest hour. Apologise for the mistake.  But how do I get the value with time as well. I do not want the time portion to be emitted completely.

Comment: What does "and actually to the nearest hour" mean?  That sounds like we're back to rounding not truncation

Comment: I have updated the question. it is truncate to the prior hour . It was typo in the comment and it does not let me change it and save back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want

```
ROUND( (TRUNC( CAST(CR_DATE AS DATE), 'HH24') - 
          DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60, 0) AS creationDate
```

`trunc(some_date, 'HH24')` will return a date truncated to the nearest hour.  Your client may not display the time component by default but it is still there.

```
with x as (
  select timestamp '2016-06-08 19:56:20.473' cr_date
    from dual
)
select ROUND( (TRUNC( CAST(CR_DATE AS DATE), 'HH24') - 
              DATE '1970-01-01') * 24 * 60 * 60, 0) AS creationDate
  from x;
```